# Maximum Possible Ways of Merging Two Arrays

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

Suppose I have two arrays of size `m` and `n`:

`a[1] a[2] a[3] ..... a[m]`

and

`b[1] b[2] b[3] ..... b[n]`

I want to form a new array merging these two arrays such that in the new array of `m + n` elements, `a[i]` is always placed befor `a[i + 1]` and `b[i]` is always placed before `b[i + 1]`. For example, `a[1] a[2] b[1] b[2]... b[n] a[m]` will be a valid array but `a[2] a[1] b[1] b[2] ... b[n] a[m]` won't. Given `m` and `n`, how many such combinations will be possible when repeating is allowed?

I have the intuition to solve the problem:

`- b[1] - b[2] - b[3] - ..... - b[n]`

I can place `a[1]` in any of the `n - 1` places within the array `b`, and considering the front and the last place, I have `n + 1` total ways of placing `a[1]`. If I place `a[1]` in the first place (just before `b[1]`), I can now place `a[2]` in `n + 1` places. But if I place `a[1]` just after `b[1]`, I would have `n` ways to place `a[2]`. I can apply this approach recursively for all `a[i]` where `1 <=i <= n`. But I can't find any mathematical formula to express the solution, besides I can't understand how to approach when repeating is allowed.

Comment: You should try math.stackexchange.com, or maybe cstheory

Comment: This is called an _interleaving_, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6801/how-do-i-determine-the-possible-number-of-combinations-of-two-ordered-sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think about this problem is the following - rather than listing off the elements in sequence, you could think about choosing, at each instant in time, whether to pick the first unused A or the first unused B.  All possible orderings of "pick A" and "pick B" will give rise to all possible ways of generating these sequences.

If you assume that all elements are distinct, then the answer would be given by the number of ways that you could permute a sequence of m A's followed by n B's.  This is given by

```
   (m + n)!
 -----------
    m!  n!
```

I don't have an answer for you in the case where there are some duplicated elements, though.  If I think of anything, I'll be sure to update this answer.

In the meantime, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks :) I knew the formula but couldn't think of the problem in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) formula. Positions of array A are the bins; into each position the corresponding element from A and any number of elements from B will be inserted. (Which elements are chosen is already determined by their original order, so we treat them as indistinguishable.) If there are (n-1) elements in A (add a bin to one end) and k elements in B, the formula gives is the binomial coefficient

```
  n + k - 1  
(            )
      k

= ( (n+k-1)! / ( k! (n-1)! )
= (a.size() + b.size())! / (a.size()! * b.size()!)
```

which is the same as templatetypedef's answer :)

Actually *calculating* the quotient of such large numbers is another issue. In most languages, the numerator will commonly produce integer overflow. One simple strategy, not necessarily optimal, in C++ would be

```
unsigned long long gcd( unsigned long long &a, unsigned long long &b )
    { return b? gcd( b, a % b ) : a; }

std::vector< std::size_t > numerator( a.size() ); // factors of (a+b)!/b!
std::iota( numerator.begin(), numerator.end(), b.size()+1 );

for ( std::size_t afactor = 2; afactor != a.size()+1; ++ afactor ) {
    std::size_t reduced = afactor;
    for ( auto &&nfactor : numerator ) {
        auto common = gcd( afactor, nfactor );
        nfactor /= common;
        reduced /= common;
        if ( reduced == 1 ) goto next_afactor;
    }
    throw std::logic_error( "Fractional combinations" );
next_afactor: ;
}

return std::accumulate( numerator.begin(), numerator.end(), 1,
                        std::multiplies< std::size_t >() );
```